# Symfony2 unable to generate url

Tags: symfony, controller, routes

first of all I'm new to Symfony2.

When I run my project it's show the next error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to 
generate a URL for the named route "/contact/" as such route does not exist.") 
in frontendiniciBundle:Default:index.html.twig at line 4.
```

The route in /frontend/iniciBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

```
frontendinici_homepage:
path:     /index/
defaults: { _controller: frontendiniciBundle:Principal:index }

frontendinici_contact:
path:     /contacto/
defaults: { _controller: frontendiniciBundle:Principal:contact }
```

And the code of the controller

```
class PrincipalController extends Controller
{
public function indexAction()
    {
    return $this->render('frontendiniciBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('contactourl' => '/contacto/'));
}

public function contactAction(){
    return $this->render('frontendiniciBundle:Default:contact.html.twig');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the name of the route, ie "frontendinici_contact" to generate it. In your Twig template, you then have to do this :

```
{{ path('frontendinici_contact') }}
```

to get the URL.